# Is it possible to extract private key from json/UTC file?

Tags: private-key

I created an ethereum paper wallet on an offline computer. Do I need to keep both the private key and the UTC/json file or can I just keep the UTC/json file and extract the private key from it. Thank you.

Comment: Note: If you forget your password, no one can do anything. It would be better if you keep your private key as your backup option.

Comment: @user19510 How to extract private key from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file contains (in encrypted form) the private key, so that's all you need.